# Where is Get-AzureADApplication?

Tags: powershell, azure, entra-id

So I have a PowerShell script that will create a new Azure AD Application using `New-AzureADApplication`.  And I can remove it later using `Remove-AzureADApplication`.  But `Remove-AzureADApplication` requires me to know the ApplicationObjectId (a guid).  How can I find this ID using PowerShell?  I'm looking for a `Get-AzureADApplication`, but it doesn't exist.  There's got to be a way to get a list of all the current applications registered in a given directory, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a service principal for this Azure AD Application you can retrieve the applicationId using the following ARM mode Azure PowerShell command:

(Get-AzureAdServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipal servicePrincipalName).ApplicationId